# como recorrer una array de este estilo con javascript, hace poco me inicie en este lenguaje ,lo quiero para representa los datos en una tabla. gracias

Tags: javascript, array, json

hace poco me inicie en javascript y la verdad es que ando algo perdido y necesito ayuda.
Necesito recorrer esta array para poder reflejar en una tabla los datos de ciertos paises determinados.
los datos estan recojidos via ajax y guardadoscon la propiedad
paisesDeseados = ***Object.entries***(paisesCoronavirus); y la verdad es que estoy algo perdido de como es la manera correcta de recorrer la array y devolver en la tabla los datos que quiero mostrar.
de antemano saludo a todos

Comment: ¿De qué estilo? ¿Cómo es el array? ¿Cómo luce? ¿Qué has intentado o investigado? ¿cuál es la manera "no correcta" que has probado? Por favor, mira [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: hay muchos metodos para recorrer arrays, los mas comunes son: ForEach() y map(), son diferentes asi que puedes investigar cual mas te conviene usar. Debes revisar si es un array o quizas lo estes confundiendo con un objeto.